# Правильно ли определены члены предложения?

Tags: сказуемые, члены-предложения, дополнение, определения, синтаксис

В каком предложении количество слов и членов предложения совпадает? Правильно ли я выделила члены предложения? Указываю только те, в которых сомневаюсь:

*Мы слышали шум голосов.* (*голосов* - опред. или допол.)

*Как соловей залетный юность пролетела.* (*как соловей залетный* - обст.)

*Мы рады весь изъездить мир.* (*изъездить* - допол., *весь мир* - дополн.)

*Никто не сможет нас согнуть в бараний рог.* (*не сможет согнуть* - сказ.; или *не сможет* - сказ.,  *согнуть* - дополн.)

*Приезд отца явился полной неожиданностью.* (*отца* - опред.; *полной неожиданностью* - дополн.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, так:

Мы слышали шум (КАКОЙ?) голосов. (голосов - опред. ) - это предл., где количество слов и членов предложения совпадает. В остальных не совпадает.

Как соловей залетный юность пролетела. (как соловей залетный - обст., потому что пролетела  как соловей = соловьём - недостаточное сравнение. Заливаться соловьём - фразеологизм, а пролететь соловьём - непонятное высказывание. )

Мы рады весь изъездить мир. В прямом значении: рады изъездить - сост. глаг. сказуемое, весь -определение, мир - дополн. Но я склонна считать выражение  "весь изъездить мир" = путешествовать  фразеологизмом, есть же такой афоризм. Тогда это всё - сост. глаг. сказуемое.

Никто не сможет нас согнуть в бараний рог. (не сможет согнуть в бараний рог - т.е. не сможет подчинить  - сост. глаг. сказ.).

Comment: Последнее - согласна со Славой

Answer (score 3):

> В каком предложении количество слов и
> членов предложения совпадает?

В первом: *Мы слышали шум голосов.*

По поводу разбора… По-моему, надо так:

> Мы рады весь изъездить мир. (изъездить
> - допол., весь мир - дополн.)

*рады изъездить* -- СГС;

*мир* -- дополн.;

*весь* -- опред.

> Никто не сможет нас согнуть в бараний
> рог. (не сможет согнуть - сказ.; или
> не сможет - сказ., согнуть - дополн.)

*не сможет согнуть в бараний рог* -- СГС.

> Приезд отца явился полной
> неожиданностью. (отца - опред.; полной
> неожиданностью - дополн.)

*явился неожиданностью* -- СИС.